# Returning error on a fetch request?

Tags: swift, nsfetchrequest

I am trying to work out how to return the error part of my do / catch statement, as its not in a function I dont have the completion to send it to and it wants to only accept NSFetchedResultsController ?

Here is the code

```
    fileprivate lazy var fetchedExercisesTodayController: NSFetchedResultsController<UserExercise> = {

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<UserExercise> = UserExercise.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "usersroutine == %@", self.routineName)

    do {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let queryResults = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)]
        let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        return fetchedResultsController

    } catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
        return error
    }
}()
```

The error is on the 'return error' line

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'Error' to return type 'NSFetchedResultsController'

Comment: You are creating a variable with lazy loading and you have said that you will absolutely return that specific class of object. If you want it to return something other than the class you have said it will be, why don't you use a function? The other option would be to handle the error in the catch instead of somewhere else, or make `fetchedExercisesTodayController` optional and return nil in the catch

Comment: how would i go about making it a function? i followed a guide to construct this one so im unsure how to convert it, do i just change it to func and add a completion handler for error?

Comment: Do you know if there was specific reason you needed to make this a lazy variable? It may be necessary that you keep it that way, if you are trying to load your view in a specific way. What do you need the error to do?

Comment: It's the way it's called throughout the VC, I'm sure it could be converted it's just a lot of changes throughout to map that code back to the functions output, at the moment it uses a property of the fetch results controller to determine its objects etc. The error I'm literally just adding to complete the statement, it doesn't really have to do anything as it won't fail, I could be wrong but that's my understanding of it

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. I'll write out a quick explanation with options below.

Answer (score 0):

If it can't fail, you don't need the try/catch at all, so just remove it.

```
fileprivate lazy var fetchedExercisesTodayController: NSFetchedResultsController<UserExercise> = {

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<UserExercise> = UserExercise.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "usersroutine == %@", self.routineName)

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let queryResults = context.fetch(fetchRequest)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)]
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

But, if you want to protect for failures, which may be possible here, you would make `fetchedExcercisesTodayController` an optional variable.  You have to make it optional because if it is not, you need to return an object of type `NSFetchedResultsController<UserExercise>` no matter what. An error is not of object type `NSFetchedResultsController<UserExercise>`. It is of object type `Error`.

If you make it optional, in the catch you could return nil and do one of three things:

- call another method that shows/does something if the try fails
- throw an error that you handle some where outside of this
- have it print an error message for you

The only problem with doing that, is that if you have already been initializing and using this variable, you will have to start unwrapping that optional  `fetchedExercisesTodayController` every where that you have used it. Essentially, both of these things will work, you just have to decide what works best for your code base.

```
//changed to NSFetchedResultsController<UserExercise>?
fileprivate lazy var fetchedExercisesTodayController: NSFetchedResultsController<UserExercise>? = {

  let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<UserExercise> = UserExercise.fetchRequest()
  fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "usersroutine == %@", self.routineName)

  do {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let queryResults = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)]
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    return fetchedResultsController

  } catch {
    print("Error with request: \(error)")
    //handle error in some way here
    return nil
  }
}()
```

Comment: thanks ill try implementing this and report back, likely will be tomorrow as its 1am here! Thanks for the ideas

Comment: Theres an issue with the non error handling option where let queryResults = context.fetch(fetchRequest) demands error handling, and in the second option it would require me to edit many areas of code throughout the VC to unwrap the now optional fetchedExercisesTodayController. Is my only other option to use a function?

Comment: The more I'm reading, you definitely want to use a lazy variable in the way you are doing it, and making it an optional won't work here.  I think you have to change your design pattern slightly. As you said,  `context.fetch` will always require error handling, so I think defining context as an implicitly unwrapped optional, setting it up in App Delegate, and handling the fetch after your lazy fetchedResultsController is initialized is ideal. This blog had the best design pattern imo: https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/03/05/displaying-data-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-swift/

Comment: Essentially, you are going to have to move calling the actual context fetch request outside of this lazy variable initialization, since you can't have something that can fail in there without the variable being optional, which we don't want- and that blog post explains the best way to do that.